# Appended File Input Preview (HTML Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to preview images that are uploaded to my page with jquery. 
The default input file I have put in my body page works and preview the image.

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="file-field input-field">
                                <div class="btn"><span>File</span><input type="file" id="file"></div>
                                <div class="file-path-wrapper"><input class="file-path validate" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I append the same thing in JQuery and use the appended input file, it doesn't preview the image.

My JQuery Code:

```
 $("#responses").append(' <div class="row"><div class="col s12 m3"><div class="card"><div class="card-content"><div class="file-field input-field"><div class="btn"><span>File</span><input type="file" id="file"></div><div class="file-path-wrapper"><input class="file-path validate" type="text"></div></div></div></div></div></div>')
```

My Javascript Code (To preview the file)

```
function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#file").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });
```

Comment: Hello, try to change `.append` to `.html(html_code_here)` or to `.innerHTML = 'html code here'`...

Comment: .html only allows for one change i want to add multiple input files

Comment: `$("#responses").html( $("#responses").html()+'html code here'`

Comment: Yeah but I can only one input file with .html . It just changed the html when i click the add button again

Comment: `$("#responses").html( $("#responses").html()+'html code here'`. If you want to use `append('html code here')` try to use `document.createElement('div')` link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you're trying to dynamically append some code on an aync event, eg. after some xhr event completes, in such cases you have to rebind the event to the newly created dom element.

So right where you're writing

```js
 $("#responses").append(' <div class="row"><div class="col s12 m3"><div class="card"><div class="card-content"><div class="file-field input-field"><div class="btn"><span>File</span><input type="file" id="file"></div><div class="file-path-wrapper"><input class="file-path validate" type="text"></div></div></div></div></div></div>')
```

You need to write the following event binding again.

```js
$("#file").change(function () {
  readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: how do i rewrite it?

Comment: It would be easier for me to help if you posted a working pen of your code.

Comment: Here's the working version https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVMNQJ?editors=1000 
I added that method hook in line 109

Comment: Thank you but it only seems to work for the first input . When I add another, it doesn't work. Is it due to similar id?

Comment: Yes, there can't be multiple elements with the same id. Also, if my solution worked for your original question please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
reader.onload =
```

To

```
reader.onloadend =
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It works for the first input file but not the appended one